# Spring async component not working

Tags: java, spring

I achieve this last Friday make it works async but I cannot anymore, and I´m getting crazy!!.

This is my current configuration for the application context.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.greenvalley.etendering">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="com.greenvalley.etendering.annotation.NoAutoScan" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <task:annotation-driven/>
```

Then I have my component.

```
       @Component
       @Transactional
       @Configuration
       @EnableAsync
       public class AsyncDocumentGenerationImpl implements            AsyncDocumentGeneration {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AsyncDocumentGenerationImpl.class);


private static final SimpleDateFormat timestampFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");

private final String mimeType = "application/pdf";
private final FileType fileType = FileType.PDF;

@Inject
private DocumentGenerationService documentGenerationService;

@Inject
private DocumentService documentService;


@Async
public Future<Integer> generateDocumentPerCandidate(final PublicProcurement publicProcurement, final DocumentType documentType, final Candidacy candidacy, final Assessment assessment)
        throws FileFormatException, DocumentServiceException, IOException, JAXBException, CmisDocumentException {

    return new AsyncResult<>(FeedbackActions.SUCCESS.getCode());
}
```

}

And the component is invoked from other service.

```
      private DeferredResult<Integer> generateDocumentsPerCandidates(DocumentGroup documentGroup, DocumentType documentType, PublicProcurement publicProcurement)
        throws FileFormatException, DocumentServiceException, IOException, JAXBException, CmisDocumentException {
    List<Future<Integer>> candidaciesResults = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Candidacy candidacy : publicProcurement.getCandidacies()) {
            Future<Integer> candidacyResult = asyncDocumentGeneration.generateDocumentPerCandidate(publicProcurement,
                    documentType, candidacy, documentGroup.getAssessment());
            candidaciesResults.add(candidacyResult);

    }
    DeferredResult<Integer> future = new DeferredResult<>();
    asyncDocumentGeneration.manageResults(candidaciesResults, future);
    return future;
}
```

I think must be something related with the applicationContext configuration, or the annotation of the async component. But the thing is than not when Invoke the async method, is not executed by other thread.

Please anyone see something weird here?.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the pool sizes explicite:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" scheduler="myScheduler"/>
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5"/>
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10"/>
```

Comment: it´s seems that now works for one async method. But now the weird is that last Friday I could cleary in the log files the async thread transaction "SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1" but now I cannot!